# Compile everything in scss folder to style.css via terminal

Tags: sass, terminal, package.json

I have the following folder structure:

```
theme
    scss
       hero.scss
       header.scss
    style.css
```

I'm trying to compile everything in the `scss` into style.css. I've followed [this tutorial](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/watch-and-compile-sass-in-five-quick-steps--cms-28275), but I believe this approach will compile several different `css` files (whereas I only want the one).

Even with the above approach, whenever I run `npm run scss`, it doesn't compile anything?

This is my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "scss": "node-sass --watch scss -o css"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

When running `npm run watch-css` or `npm run scss`, nothing happens? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: hi did my answer help/make sense?

Answer (score 0):

*Your input directory and output directories are incorrect* for the `node-sass` command. Assuming you've the following directory structure:

```
theme
    scss
      hero.scss
      header.scss
    style.css
package.json
```

You've created an npm run script called `scss` which is leveraging the `node-sass` library to compile your SASS into CSS. If you want to execute this run script you should type the following into your command line: `npm run scss`

Now when you type this command you're actually running the `node-sass` library with these parameters:

```
node-sass --watch scss -o css
```

In this command, you've specified that your Sass files exist in your `scss` directory and `node-sass` should look in this directory to compile your Sass into CSS. Once this is done your newly generated CSS is moved into your `css` directory.

However, the first issue is you **don't have css directory** for `node-sass` to put these compiled Sass files into. *You can remedy this by either creating a `css` folder within your `theme` directory or modifying your output location parameter appropriately*.

The other issue is your **input directory location is incorrect** for your Sass files. You've specified it as the `scss` directory *however this location is relative to your `package.json` file and there is `theme` folder in-between said files.* This should probably be changed to the following: `theme/scss`.

So in order to get it this command to work appropriately you need to change your input and output directories to point to the correct directory structure of your application.

Perhaps you could try changing your run script to the following and seeing if this helps (**Assuming you don't want to create a `css` folder**):

```
"scss": "node-sass --watch theme/scss -o theme"
```

then re-run your npm script like so:

```
npm run scss
```

Hopefully that helps!